# Django path not resetting after use of form

Tags: django, forms, templates, view

On a page called games/vote I have a form that uses the path "add_title/" as its action:

```
<form method="post" action="add_title/" method="post">
```

I return the following from the associated view:

```
return render_to_response('games/votes.html', {'vote_list': not_owned_vote_list,},
                        context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

The url then remains at games/vote/add_title upon return from the view.

I tried changing the path and path_info attributes of the request but to no avail:

```
request.path = "/games/vote/"
request.path_info = "/games/vote/"
```

I want the path to be /games/vote upon return to the web page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By 'path' do you mean the URL in the address bar? If so, `render_to_response` just returns a response to the browser.  You would need to use `redirect` or similar to change the url that the user sees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the path like that. The only way to do it is to tell the browser to redirect to a different URL - which, in fact, is exactly the thing you are [recommended to do by the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) after a form POST.

```
if form.is_valid():
    ... process ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/games/vote/')
```

(Also you should look at using named URLs and [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) rather than hard-coding the URLs.)